# Injecting ISession in FluentValidation AbstractValidator

Tags: fluentvalidation

Trying to work out the best way of getting NHibernate ISession into a fluent validation abstract validator. Issue is that ISession is registered as per web request and validators are registered as singleton as per fluent's best practices for performance reasons. This obviously causes issues with ISession being disposed before its needed.

Any tips greatly appreciated, trying to avoid passing in the container instance

Comment: Did you end up coming up with a solution you were happy with?

Comment: Yeah, switched to node.js :-)

Comment: LOL. I guess that's one way of dealing with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the TypedFactoryFacility, the easiest is to use a delegate, see http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-delegate-based-factories.ashx

I would however suggest using interface based factories because firstly you can explicitly release the session when you're done with it, and secondly it's more evident in the code what you're doing, see http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx